# Discovering IOT Devices In Network Logs

Tags: aws-iot, smart-lights, smart-assistants

How we can discover IoT Devices used within a network in Firewall Logs?.

One of the way of discovering IOT devices is through mac address, but mac address is not available in log file. I have to work around with header(User-Agent, Source IP , Client IP and Request Url) to uniquely identify an IoT device.

I am getting logs from BlueCoat Proxysg.
Fields available in firewall logs are https://origin-symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/webguides/cacheflow/3x/3_4/webguide/Content/CPL/Access-Log-Fields.htm

I want to detect all kind of IOT Devices used in my networks.

Comment: You probably need to update the question to be a little more specific. Where are you collecting the logs and using what tools. Also are you looking to discover specific types of devices on your network or any devices present.

Comment: "`I want to detect all kind of IOT Devices used in my networks`" - are we talking a closed LAN or WAN here, or can these devices be accessing your network form outside. If the latter, I doubt that it will be doable.  Great question !

Comment: in my WAN Network.